# How to find hidden php code in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, hidden

I have found in one of my Wordpress websites source code hidden php code. This is what I am looking for. I see it in the view source view, but I cannot find it in the wordpress theme files. Where could it be located?

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: -1236px; overflow: auto; width:1241px;"><span>Designed by </span> <h3><a href="http://bestdownfree.com/">best down free</a> | <a href="http://webphunuso.com/">web phu nu so</a> | <a href="http://webphunuso.com/category/lam-dep/kieu-toc-dep/">toc dep 2017</a></h3></div><p class="demo_store"><b>FREE GIFT WITH ANY INK OR TONER CARTRIDGE PURCHASE! HAPPY PRINTING FROM SOS INK</b></p>      <script type="text/javascript">
```

Comment: I cannot spot _any_ php code in that, "hidden" or not.

Comment: Might be a cross site scripting attack. Wordpress is well known to be highly vulnerable to all sorts of attacks.

Comment: The styling could have been added by some script, maybe take a look through the script file and check for the footer element.

Comment: @P.Samuel I checked in the footer element but has not  found anything in there

Comment: Can you add a link to the website so I can look for it?

Comment: @nogad this was injected in the code by someone and hidden.. it has nothing to do with the branding

Comment: @P.Samuel https://sosink.com here is the link. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, but you *can't* see php code in the source code of a website which is shown in the browser! php code is parsed by the server, whish sends HTML, CSS, JS etc. to the browser, but definitely no PHP. So what is your question?

Comment: @Johannes yeah I know I made a mistake I am looking for the HTML code mentioned above.

Comment: Okey so I'm 99% sure it's not being added by a script, it might be a php file that outputs that somewhere, take a look at the index file and other accociated references in the index file, you might find the answer there.

Comment: @P.Samuel ok I will do so now. Thanks a lot for the help

Comment: you can deactivate the plugins one for one and check if it's still there... (and also the theme)

Comment: @P.Samuel I found it, you were right it was comming from a plugin. Thanks again

Comment: No problem man, you should try to look throughly in your files before giving up, just some food for thought :)

Answer (score 2):

These ads usually added by some PHP Code by a Hacked/Illegal Plugin or Theme.

In this case an useful way to find it, is to scan your project for 'base64_decode(' string, because these ads commonly come from a decoded string to be unfindable by searcing for it's content.

Your project will likely contain something like this:

```
$html ="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";
echo base64_decode($html);
```

After you found these malicious lines, you can remove them. But don't forget, base64_decode doesn't do anything wrong by itself, so dont remove all these functions. If you put the content of the string to an online Base64 Decoder, you can check it's real content, and remove it if it's something bad.

*Other info: By Switcing of Plugins / Themes you can also find out which one does it (check when it's gone), and after that you don't need to scan your whole project, just these plugins/themes files.*

***There are many other ways to do this inject, so it's not a guaranteed method. Look update for finding other types of malware.***

***Update:***

The following program can come very handy at finding infected files, it can have some false positive results too (says malware to a normal file), but at least it founds the malwares.

Link: [PHP MALWARE SCANNER](https://github.com/scr34m/php-malware-scanner)